# Add value in different column based on a key in result list

Tags: mysql

I bet my title is not clear so there is a table of what I want.

I have this :

```
+------+---------+-------+
|LOGIN |   KEY   | VALUE |
+------+---------+-------+
|JDE001|LASTNAME |Doe    |
|JDE001|FIRSTNAME|John   |
|RRE001|LASTNAME |Roe    |
|RRE001|FIRSTNAME|Richard|
+------+---------+-------+
```

I'd like :

```
    +------+--------+---------+
    |LOGIN |LASTNAME|FIRSTNAME|
    +------+--------+---------+
    |JDE001|Doe     |John     |
    |RRE001|Roe     |Richard  |
    +------+--------+---------+
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple pivot query here.  The trick is that for each pair of records belonging to a given login we pivot out the first and last name into separate columns using `MAX()` along with a `CASE` expression.

```
SELECT
    LOGIN,
    MAX(CASE WHEN `KEY`='LASTNAME'  THEN VALUE END) AS LASTNAME,
    MAX(CASE WHEN `KEY`='FIRSTNAME' THEN VALUE END) AS FIRSTNAME
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY LOGIN
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: How many times are you going to answer these questions rather than closing them down as duplicate?

Comment: @Shadow The data looked real to me, so I thought it wasn't a homework dump.  Granted, little effort was shown, but it seemed like a real question.

Comment: It does not matter whether a question is homework or a real one - if it's been answered before, then it is a duplicate. This is the 4th mysql pivot table question I have encountered today.